# Problems converting image data to unsigned int types for use with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have an 8-bit `.gif` image that I'm able to read into a Numpy array of dtype `uint8`. However, when I try to convert the dtype to a larger type of integer, such as `uint32` and `uint64`, for use in OpenCV, I get weird errors.

I'm using Google Colab and am running Python 3.6.

I downloaded this 8-bit color gif image:

```
!wget https://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~pmeerw/Watermarking/lena_color.gif
```

And here's my code below where I try to convert the image to each of `[ np.uint8, np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64 ]` and then draw a rectangle.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib

print(np.__version__)          # 1.19.5
print(cv2.__version__)         # 4.1.2
print(matplotlib.__version__)  # 3.2.2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


img_orig = mpimg.imread('lena_color.gif')
print('img_orig dtype: %s' % img_orig.dtype) # img_orig dtype: uint8

# Coordinates for rectangle to be drawn.
TL = (100, 100)
BR = (400, 400)

# Convert to different integer dtypes.
dtypes = [ np.uint8, np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64 ]

for dtype in dtypes:

    print('Changing type to %s' % (dtype.__name__))

    img = img_orig.astype(dtype)
    try:
        cv2.rectangle(img, TL, BR, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        _ = plt.imshow(img)
        _ = plt.show()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

I get the following results:

```
Changing type to uint8
```

[image]

```
Changing type to uint16
```

[image]

```
Changing type to uint32
an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

```
Changing type to uint64
```

[image]

**Specific questions**:

1. Why do I get an exception when I change the dtype to `uint32` ?
2. I drew the rectangle with blue `(0, 0, 255)`. Why is the rectangle coming out as kind of white-purple?
3. Why does the rectangle not appear when the dtype is `uint64` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are happening here. First, you are using `OpenCV` and `matplotlib`. These are different imaging libraries that are not 100% compatible among themselves. `OpenCV` uses `BGR` color channel ordering while `matplotlib` uses `RGB`. If you process the image using a function from `OpenCV` (such as `cv2.rectangle`) expect to operate on reversed channels, if you loaded or are showing the image with `matplotlib`.

Now, for your first question. Image types are normally encoded using 8 unsigned bits per channel. That is `8 x 3` bits for a `BGR` (or `RGB`) image, although you can also have `8 x 1` bits for greyscale images, or 8 x 4 bits for a `BGRA` (the last channel being the Alpha channel - the transparency channel. Every type outside of those cases could be unsupported for a set of functions. In the case of `OpenCV`, `cv2.rectangle` does not support arrays of the type `uint32` nor `uint64`. In fact, I get an exception using BOTH formats.

Now, the rectangle. You draw the rectangle using `OpenCV` and show it using `matplotlib`, so  expect the color you set on the rectangle function to not match what you see on the screen. This image file, in particular, is a `.gif` with an extra  transparency channel, making it a `RGBA` (4 channels) image. You are setting the color with three parameters, however, `cv2.rectangle` only appears to be affecting the alpha channel, setting it to `255`. The solution is to convert the `RGBA` image to an `RGB` image using [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab):

```
# Include this line just before drawing the rectangle:
# Conversion from RGBA to RGB:
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```

So you will see the correct result on screen:

[image]

Advices:

1. If you are going to use multiple imaging libraries be aware of their differences and possible compatibility issues
2. Operate and show `BGR` or `RGB` images only, other types are usually mid-operation temporal results
3. If processing `.gif`s, check out how many channels they are using. Images (at least as `OpenCV` requires them) are represented as `numpy` arrays. You can check the dimensions of a `numpy` array using [`shape`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html)

Like this:

```
(height, width, channels) = img.shape
print((height, width, channels))
```

For the Lena image, this returns:

```
(512, 512, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you. You wrote `Image types are normally encoded using 8 unsigned bits per channel`. Does that mean that my Numpy data for 3-channel color images always has to have `dtype=np.uint8`? Also, why did my code work when I used `uint16`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 That's correct, `RGB/BGR` images are usually encoded in 3-channel numpy `uint8` arrays. `uint16` is a less common but also valid image encoding, [JPEG 2000](https://www.design-reuse.com/sip/scalable-uhd-jpeg-2000-encoder-8-up-to-16-bits-per-component-lossy-or-numerically-lossless-image-video-compression-ip-47508/) uses this bit depth.

Answer (score 1):

Your image has an alpha channel.  That means each pixel has 4 components (R,G,B,A), not just three.  You should print the image arrays to see what they contain.  When you specify (0,0,255), it defaults to 0 for the alpha.  That means you're seeing the background show through.  The rectangle will be whatever color the background window was at that point.  If you specify (0,0,255,255), you will see the blue you expect.

Also note that it really serves no purpose to change the datatype of the numpy arrays.  The components are taken as values from 0 to 255, regardless of the datatype of the components.

Comment: Thank you. `uint32` and `uint64` certainly contain 0 to 255, so why did my code break?

Comment: Not sure.  OpenCV has to guess what your image is based on the types.  What you're giving it is not a normal image type.  When it sees elements of type uint32, it is apparently guessing that what you have is not an RGBA image.  What were you hoping to accomplish by this, anyway?

Comment: I was trying to convert a black-and-white image with 0.0 - 1.0 float values to RGB by multiplying the image array by 255 and then casting to integer. I realize now that I have to cast using `.astype(np.uint8)`.